# Handle specific (for io) exception separately

Tags: python, error-handling, exception

Some IO operations produce some set of errors. It is important, that it is not one exception, but set. So, we have set for socket errors, set for file io. How to handle group of exceptions without intersection for different io operations?

For example, `OSError` handles file io errors and some(?) Socket errors.

I have only one solution: wrap io operations with try-except and raise user-defined exception.

```
def foo():
    try:
        # some file io
    except:
        raise MyFileIOException(reason=sys.exc_info())

    try:
        # some socket io
    except:
        raise MySocketIOException(reason=sys.exc_info())

def bar():
    try:
        foo()
    except MyFileIOException as exc:
        # handle
    except MySocketIOException as exc:
        # handle
```

Is there some better and elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm ended with:

```
def decorator(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return (yield from f(*args, **kwargs))
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            raise
        except:
            raise CustomError(reason=sys.exc_info())
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have written a decent exception-handler. Moreover, it depends upon scenario. Say for eg. If you are making a function in library, then it's advisable not to introduce any application/domain specific exception types in the library function and simply raise raw/native exception types. When application code will use that function, it's its responsibility to declare its own set of exception types and wrap the exception generated in library into its own type.

eg. Library's code

```
def WriteToFile(strFile, strCnt):
  objFile = open(strFile, "w")
  objFile.write(strCnt)
  objFile.close()
```

StudentRecord Application code

```
import library   # import our library in which SaveStudent is present
import sys
def SaveStudent(objStudent):
   try:
      WriteToFile("studentRec.txt", str(objStudent))
   except IOError as e:
      raise StudentSaveFailedException, None, sys.exc_info()[2]
```

Now let this exception be handled in the application's Exception-handler component, which will meaningfully handle this exception and take necessary corrective actions.

Though I know that it's a naive explaination, but this is the strategy used in larger application, which uses several in-house and 3rd party libraries for proper exception handling.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: `raise StudentSaveFailedException, None, sys.exc_info()[2]` is `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Oh, it's only for 2. Got it.